# Selenium Grid - Webdriver - Whitescreens when running tests

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js

So typically I do these steps to run a test

1. Start selenium grid (`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub // java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node`)
2. Run a test script (node test.js // nightwatch test.js | `node test.js`)
3. Webdriver kicks off browser and starts test

These scripts used to work and after revisiting them after a couple months I found they are now broken. I am unsure what the problem is  as I have not changed any code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI

**Selenium version: 2.39.0 |
OS: Mac Yosemite |
Browser: Firefox  |
Browser version: 34.0.5**

After 'starting' the server and going to

```
http://localhost:4444/
```

i get

"You are using grid 2.39.0
Find help on the official selenium wiki : more help here
default monitoring page : console"

but when trying to run a night watch script or even 'nightwatch help' it fails and then gives me the error - 'Connection refused! Is selenium server started?'  (node scripts also give me a white screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this webdriver doesn't like the newer versions of firefox.

If you are experiencing issues go grab Firefox v 28.0 https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/28.0/mac/en-GB/